# How do I prove the finiteness of the numbers' set that's outside the epsilon range?

Tags: calculus, limits

I managed to prove that $$\frac{1}{2^n+n}$$ has a limit and it's $0$ (by definition of limit).

Now I'm interested in figuring out how to prove that the set of numbers of the sequence that are outside the *epsilon range* is finite: $$\left\{n\in N \colon \tfrac{1}{2^n+n} \ge \epsilon\right\}.$$

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier than you realize: Given $\epsilon$, you showed that there's some integer $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$, $\frac 1 {2^n + n} < \epsilon$. Thus $\{k\in\mathbb{N}\mid \frac 1 {2^k + k} \ge \epsilon\}$ is included in the finite set $\{0, 1, \ldots, N-1\}$, so it's finite.

Comment: Is it the formal way of proofing that? Can I go into more detailed answer?

Comment: It's a proof, so let's say yes. I fixed a typo (oops): in the set after "Thus" I still had $n$, but it should have been $k$. I also added a few (obvious) words to the last sentence to make it clearer. Detailed and correct enough to follow now?

Comment: Wow, after I read your answer 2-3 times more I got the point. Thanks

Comment: Oh good. See, it's not that complex. If the $n^{th}$ term is $\ge \epsilon$, then $n$ can't be $\ge N$, it has to to be $< N$. Maybe if I'd said that you wouldn't have needed the rereads.